# Page Resize isn't Moving Div along with the page

Tags: html, css

In a section of my page, I have some text on the left and a grid on the right. Now, when I try to lower the width of the page, instead of the grid moving along with the page (when the width is being decreased), it remains stationary and ends up getting covered by the page. Furthermore at a certain point of page width, there is overflow on the x-axis. It looks something like this:

[image]

However, when the page width is lowered, the grid just doesn't move, and gets covered; stays stationary, as shown below.

[image]

```
<!-- Third Section -->

<div class="index-third">
  <div class="index-third-text">
    <p id="heading">How We Can Help You</p>
    <h4 id="subheading">Our Services</h4>
    <hr>
    <h5 id="body">The services we offer are to ensure seamless consultation <br> processes. These features intend to provide necessary <br> and effective remote medical support to those in need. <br> <br> Click on the buttons to learn more!</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="index-third-grid">
    <div class="item item-1">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
      <p>Search</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-2">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-check-to-slot"></i>
      <p>Consult</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-3">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-comment"></i>
      <p>Chat</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-4">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-list"></i>
      <p>Diagnose</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-5">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-bars-progress"></i>
      <p>Manage</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-6">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
      <p>Review</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.item {
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 15px;
        width: 160px;
        height: 100px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px black;
      }

      .item p {
        margin-top: 20px;
      }

      .index-third-grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: 100px;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
        row-gap: 2em;
        column-gap: 5em;
        margin: 100px;
        margin-left: 750px;
        color: #704a1b;
        font-size: 20px;
      }

      .index-third-text p {
        font-size: 25px;
        color: #704a1b;
        margin-left: 100px;
        position: absolute;
      }

      .index-third-text h4 {
        font-size: 35px;
        color: #614124;
        margin-left: 100px;
        margin-top: 40px;
        position: absolute;
      }

      .index-third-text h5 {
        font-size: 15px;
        color: #614124;
        margin-left: 130px;
        margin-top: 120px;
        position: absolute;
      }

      .index-third-text hr {
        font-size: 35px;
        border: 0.5px solid #614124;
        width: 0px;
        height: 120px;
        margin-left: 100px;
        margin-top: 110px;
        position: absolute;
      }
```

Comment: You will need to specify breakpoints

Comment: The grid first starts getting covered at 1310px

Comment: You need some more context in here. The `.item` elements overflowing off screen is because of the width/layout of the parent container. Without the styles for this, we can't help solve the answer. You probably want to use something like flexbox or grid with breakpoints.

Comment: Should I provide the entire page's code?

Comment: @reddy_boi34 All of the CSS and HTML for that block, yes. The best thing to do would be to put it in a [codepen](https://codepen.io/) or use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo. Then we can see what is going on and help.