# How to Stack DIVs on top of each based on screen width

Tags: html, css

I have these two `div` classes next to each other. The one on the left is text and the one on the right is a `grid`. Now, I implemented code using the media queries between `1050px` and `1280px` to change the rows and columns of the grid when the screen width is lowered. However, below `1049px`, there isn't enough space anymore, and so I want the `divs` to be stacked on top of each other, the text on the top and the `div` on the bottom, and I want to make both of the `divs` be at the center of the screen, no matter what the screen width is below `1049px`.

```css
.item {
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 15px;
        width: 160px;
        height: 100px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px black;
      }

      .item p {
        margin-top: 20px;
      }

      .index-third-grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: 100px;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
        row-gap: 2em;
        column-gap: 5em;
        color: #704a1b;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin: 100px;
        margin-right: 170px;
        margin-top: -10px;
        float: right;
      }

      .index-third-text {
        margin-top: 70px;
      }

      .index-third-text p {
        font-size: 25px;
        color: #704a1b;
        margin-left: 100px;
        position: absolute;
      }

      .index-third-text h4 {
        font-size: 35px;
        color: #614124;
        margin-left: 100px;
        margin-top: 40px;
        position: absolute;
      }

      .index-third-text h5 {
        font-size: 15px;
        color: #614124;
        margin-left: 130px;
        margin-top: 120px;
        position: absolute;
      }

      .index-third-text hr {
        font-size: 35px;
        border: 0.5px solid #614124;
        width: 0px;
        height: 120px;
        margin-left: 100px;
        margin-top: 110px;
        position: absolute;
      }

      @media screen and (min-width: 1050px) and (max-width: 1280px) {
        .index-third-grid {
          grid-template-rows: 100px;
          grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 100px);
          margin-top: -100px;
        }

        .index-third-text {
          margin-top: 150px;
        }

        body {
          overflow-x: hidden;
        }
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 1049px) {
        /* Part I'm Confused About */
      }
```

```html
<div class="index-third">
  <div class="index-third-text">
    <p id="heading">How We Can Help You</p>
    <h4 id="subheading">Our Services</h4>
    <hr>
    <h5 id="body">The services we offer are to ensure seamless consultation <br> processes. These features intend to provide necessary <br> and effective remote medical support to those in need. <br> <br> Click on the buttons to learn more!</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="index-third-grid">
    <div class="item item-1">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
      <p>Search</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-2">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-check-to-slot"></i>
      <p>Consult</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-3">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-comment"></i>
      <p>Chat</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-4">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-list"></i>
      <p>Diagnose</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-5">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-bars-progress"></i>
      <p>Manage</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-6">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
      <p>Review</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This should really be part of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76796421/page-resize-isnt-moving-div-along-with-the-page.

Comment: I fixed that. The grid is moving along with the page now. Now, what I want to do is when it goes below `1049px`, the divs should stack on top of each other, while being at the center of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're using `position: absolute;` on everything in the left column. By doing that you take it out of the flow and it has 0 height, so thing things overlap.

Instead put the whole section in an outer grid and as the correct size, change it from one column to 2.

---

UPDATED: This is a more bulletproof set of styles and it will handle all of the scaling. Plus I fixed a few of the markup issues around headings.

Take a look into semantic markup. It will help you understand how to write better and more accessible HTML.

Also, look into grid auto-fit and auto-fill. That would give you a better and even more fluid version of the grid you have on the right.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.index-third {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding: 70px 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px black;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

.item p {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.index-third-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  gap: 1rem;
  color: #704a1b;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.index-third-text h1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #704a1b;
}

.index-third-text h2 {
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #614124;
}

.index-third-text p {
  border-left: 1px solid #614124;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #614124;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 530px) and (max-width: 1050px) {
  .index-third-grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
  .index-third-grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1049px) {
  .index-third {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="index-third">
  <div class="index-third-text">
    <h1 id="heading">How We Can Help You</h1>
    <h2 id="subheading">Our Services</h2>
    <p id="body">The services we offer are to ensure seamless consultation <br> processes. These features intend to provide necessary <br> and effective remote medical support to those in need. <br> <br> Click on the buttons to learn more!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="index-third-grid">
    <div class="item item-1">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
      <p>Search</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-2">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-check-to-slot"></i>
      <p>Consult</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-3">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-comment"></i>
      <p>Chat</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-4">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-list"></i>
      <p>Diagnose</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-5">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-bars-progress"></i>
      <p>Manage</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-6">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
      <p>Review</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach to the problem presented is below, with explanatory comments in the code to try and explain how that code works:

```css
/* setting CSS custom properties on the root element, in most contexts
   this will be the <html> element: */
:root {
  /* used to indicate the number of columns within a given element: */
  --columnCount: 2;
  /* used to assign the inline-size of an element, this is - in ltr
     and rtl languages - equivalent to "width," but will also apply
     to the inline-axis of other languages, such as top-to-bottom: */
  --inlineSize: 80%;
}

/* using a media query along with the range syntax, to update the
   --columnCount property for situations where the viewport is
   less than 1050px: */
@media screen and (width < 1050px) {
   :root {
    --columnCount: 1;
  }
}

/* simple reset to remove all default margin and padding,
   setting the box-sizing algorithm to 'border-box' in
   order that the assigned element-size includes both
   the border-widths and the padding: */
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* rather than setting margins on the child elements of
   the <body> I'm using padding-block-start, and padding
   inline; these set the padding on the leading edge of
   the block-axis (the top, for ltr and rtl top-to-bottom
   languages), and on both edges of the horizontal axis
   for those languages: */
body {
  padding-block-start: 70px;
  padding-inline: 2rem;
}

.index-third {
  display: grid;
  gap: 2rem;
  /* using the repeat() function to set the desired
     number of columns, each of the (approximate)
     same size: */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columnCount), 1fr);
  inline-size: var(--inlineSize);
  margin-inline: auto;
}

#heading,
#subheading {
  /* your demo had the text very close together, I don't
     know if that was a feature or a bug, so I replicated
     it (though I do feel it's a little visually crowded),
     if it was a bug, however, just remove this declaration: */
  line-height: 1;
}

/* using rems to define the font-sizes, to allow for a user's
   changes of zoom levels, or base font-size, to cause all
   fonts to proportionally scale with that choice: */
#heading {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

#subheading {
  font-size: 3rem;
  /* using padding to push the following sibling element
     further away from the content of this element: */
  padding-block-end: 1em;
}

#body {
  /* using a border instead of an unnecessary <hr>, which is
     semantically used to separate content, whereas this
     (seems) purely visual, so a border seemed more appropriate,
     although a background-image would be equally valid in
     context: */
  border-inline-start: 3px solid #000;
  padding-block: 1rem;
  padding-inline-start: 3rem;
}

#body p:not(:first-child) {
  margin-block-start: 0.5em;
}

.index-third-grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  /* setting each row of the grid to 6.25rem, which sizes the elements
     in each row to that size and - again - using rems to size the
     rows in order that when/if the user zooms, or adjusts font-size,
     the "buttons" will adjust in size to contain the text (though this
     is somewhat undermined by the strict requirement of three columns: */
  grid-auto-rows: 6.25rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(10rem, 1fr));
}

/* the biggest change I've made here, really, is the removal of explict
   widths, offsets, margins...all of which can be handled better by
   the grid-layout system; and again I'm using grid layout here to
   center the content.
   I've also chosen to use display: grid, in order to use
   place-items to center the elements (though you may prefer to use
   place-content: center): */
.item {
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
  display: grid;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 0.5em;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css">
<div class="index-third">
  <div class="index-third-text">
    <p id="heading">How We Can Help You</p>
    <h4 id="subheading">Our Services</h4>
    <div id="body">
      <!-- here I've removed the <hr> and all the <br> elements, replaced the <h5> with a <div>
           keeping the same id, and enforced content breaks by wrapping each separated part of the
           text in individual paragraphs: -->
      <p>The services we offer are to ensure seamless consultation processes.</p>
      <p>These features intend to provide necessary and effective remote medical support to those in need.</p>
      <p>Click on the buttons to learn more!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="index-third-grid">
    <div class="item item-1">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
      <p>Search</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-2">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-check-to-slot"></i>
      <p>Consult</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-3">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-comment"></i>
      <p>Chat</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-4">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-list"></i>
      <p>Diagnose</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-5">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-bars-progress"></i>
      <p>Manage</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-6">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
      <p>Review</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xdq3nt6b/).

References:

- [`border-inline-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-inline-start).
- [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius).
- [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow).
- [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).
- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`font-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size).
- [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap).
- [`grid-auto-rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-rows).
- [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns).
- [`inline-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inline-size).
- [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height).
- [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).
- [`margin-block-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block-start).
- [`margin-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline).
- [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).
- [`padding-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-block).
- [`padding-block-end`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-block-end).
- [`padding-block-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-block-start).
- [`padding-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-inline).
- [`padding-inline-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-inline-start).
- [`place-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-content).
- [`place-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-items).